# Helping a lazy person

Tags: islamic-basis, helping

Assalam alaikum.I want to know whether not doing help is a sin or not.. I know that we should help the people in need and also poor people..but if friends or any person asks help,.. we can do as it is a good deed..but is it compulsory to do??.. if not then is it a sin? Also When a person who is lazy to do some kind of work.. Asking us help..then is it permissible to refuse to help..? Because I remember the hadith that .. when a person refuse to do help inspite of capable enough is it a sin??. Kindly answer me this professionally.. I'm waiting a lot many days to get answer for this..